# IBM RFT: Not starting application

Tags: java, user-interface, testing, rft

I'm using RFT 8.2 with it's Eclipse Version but my own java program doesn't start within the RFT's recording function.

- It's just a small GUI for RFT exploration purpose and I selected it's class in RFT application setup.
- Of couse I can start it normally in Eclipse.
- I can start the RFT's Testing Templates (ClassicsJavaA & ClassicsJavaB)

Tell me if you need any additional specific info.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not a RFT user but I would look at the Eclipse Error Log (Window ->Show View -> Error Log). Is there any error?

Comment: No error there but thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is caused because the class is located in a package and the standard rft boot line doesn't address this circumstance.

I solved it by writing the correct class path in the "path" lines and also writing the packagename before the class (like you would start the program with the CMD line).

**RFT Application Wizard:**

Path: `C:\YourPath\bin` (Eclipse Class folder)

Class- Or Jar: `package.packageTwo.KlassName`

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned how exactly you are trying to start your application(How have you configured your application , what is the type  of your application)
Using the RFT's "Configure Application for Testing" wizard you can add a java application (if you want to execute a JAR application) or  you can add ane Executable  (EXE) if your application is in EXE form.

If the application you want to run is a class file thn you can configure  "java.exe/javaw.exe "in the applicaton wizard and the give the name of the class as an argument .

Comment: yea, I want to start my program as a class file.
Please give me an example of the argument - the application wizard leaves this textfield blank.

Comment: When I export the class into an executeable jar file it works.

Comment: I think the problem is caused, because the class is located in a package and then the standard code line RFT uses is not correct.